# How to make the same WiFi adapter work on two different networks with different DHCP configurations?

Tags: wireless-networking, ip, dhcp, network-adapter, wireless-adapter

I have a tablet that is going to be used in two networks:

One network has DHCP deactivated while the second one has it activated and uses a different range of IP adresses. The problem is that if I specify the IP adress in the adapter settings then the tablet does not automatically connect to the second network.

I want to automate the process for this tablet that runs Windows 8, maybe creating some kind of virtual adapter for each network. It is going to be used by my mom (i.e. a person who cannot change the settings every time he uses the tablet), that's why setting the IP adress every time it connects to the first network is not an option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try with the "Alternate Configuration" that is present since windows 7 onwards.

This config allows you to set the static IP/MASK/DNS as the alternate config which will be used if no DHCP server is found on the WLAN.

In order to do so you need to go to Network and Sharing Center -> Change Adapter Settings -> (select your WLAN adapter) -> Properties -> Internet Protocol Version 4 -> Properties -> Alternate Configuration.

In the General configuration you should leave "Obtain IP address automatically" while on the "Alternate configuration" you should configure the static params of your other network.

There is a very illustrative post in the fourth answer of this question ([Obtaining a DHCP IP address if static address is not available](https://superuser.com/questions/443147/obtaining-a-dhcp-ip-address-if-static-address-is-not-available)).

Hope it helps!