# Assign what IP should get what gateway

Tags: networking

I have two internet modem, modem A and modem B, they get internet from different service providers

Also, I have an access point that Wi-Fi devices may connect to that.

My router is a hap lite MikroTik router, Wi-Fi access point and modem A and modem B and one PC connects to my router four ethernet ports. And Wi-Fi devices connect to Wi-Fi access point **or** router Wi-Fi (depends on signal strength, wifi clients may connect to Wi-Fi access point SSID or router Wi-Fi SSID)

I want to do this:
Divide devices in two group, group A and group B, all of the clients in group A should access to clients group B and vice versa, but their internet gateway is different:

Group  A should connect to internet just by modem A, if modem A failed to connect to internet, group A shouldn't have access to internet,

Group B should connect to internet by modem B, but if modem B failed to connect to internet, group B should have access to internet by modem A.

How can I do that? can I assign different gateways to different devices into the router settings!? remember that I don't want to set any IP settings on devices, everything should be done in router side.

[image: This is diagram]

Comment: Are the modems in the same subnet as the client devices? (that is, are their ports on the hAP bridged to the rest of the LAN?) Are the modems themselves also routers? The diagram is useful but doesn't really say enough about what the IP configuration is like.

Comment: @user1686 Yes, because modems just connected to the router. their DHCP is off, modems are in bridge mode. yes, the modems are also routers. sorry if diagram doesn't say enough information, if you need any other information I will provide.

Comment: What do the computers have as their gateways? If it's one of the modems, then set it manually.

Comment: @harrymc and how to perform fail over then?

Comment: You might try in *Settings > Network & Internet > Change adapter options*, to right click the adapter, Properties, Internet Protocol Version 4 (TCP/ IPv4), Properties, to set the Alternative Configuration to the other one. See [link](https://superuser.com/questions/292524/what-is-the-alternate-configuration-tab-in-tcp-ip-settings).

Comment: @harrymc but can I do this in other devices such android phone or ios? or just limited to windows?

Comment: @harrymc also, this is only works when my connection breaks with ISP, but not work when ISP connection break with internet (or when my internet quota finish)

Comment: The keyword here is policy routing, but I'm not familiar with how to do it on RouterOS.

Answer (score 0):

To do a seamless fallback from one failed modem to the other,
you need a dual-WAN router.

This is a router that has two WAN ports, so connects to two ISPs.
It will do load balancing, in effect using both ISPs in parallel
with a combined bandwidth, and will also handle failover.

Comment: You mean that I can't do failover without dual-WAN router? I can perform a seamless fallback with "Netwatch" in mikrotik.